# combining an area chart with a line chart in highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So I have an area stacked chart:

```
chart: {
      type: 'area',
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'normal',
      },
      area: {
        events: {
          legendItemClick: function () {
            return false; // <== returning false will cancel the default action
          },
        },
      },
    },
    title: {
      text: title,
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      min: startDateInMS,
      max: endDateInMS,
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: yLabel,
      },
    },
    series: data,
    credits: {
      enabled: false,
    },
  };
```

How do I add a line item/chart to what I already have? I have looked through the docs and they don't really have an example of combining a line with an area chart.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Highcharts support combining different kinds of charts like so:

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/combining-chart-types

```
series: [{
        type: 'area',
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'John',
        data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
    },
```

Combining area and line would look something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/henrikskar/ateje82r/

Comment: thats a little different than how i have my chart set up. if you notice I set up the chart type at the top and then the series at the bottom. so that example doesn't really show me how to add a line to my current area chart. sorry.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with your code? Will make it easier for me to help you that way. :)